# MySQL: Query to count how many times the last day of several months are found between a data range

Tags: mysql

I have a database that keeps tracks of customers contracts.
Each contract have an effective period, and this is stored as dates in contract_start and contract_end.

I would like to create a view that displays at the end of each month how many contracts were active on each customer.

The following query shows the dumb way of doing it, I would like to know if it is possible to create a "loop" that does this automatically:

```
SELECT 
    '2018-01-31' AS snapshot_day,
    customer,
    COUNT(*) AS active_contracts
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    contract_start < '2018-02-01'
        AND contract_end >= '2018-02-01'
GROUP BY 2

UNION SELECT 
    '2018-02-28' AS snapshot_day,
    customer,
    COUNT(*) AS active_contracts
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    contract_start < '2018-03-01'
        AND contract_end >= '2018-03-01'
GROUP BY 2

UNION SELECT 
    '2018-03-30' AS snapshot_day,
    customer,
    COUNT(*) AS active_contracts
FROM
    my_table
WHERE
    contract_start < '2018-04-01'
        AND contract_end >= '2018-04-01'
GROUP BY 2

.
.
.

and so on
```

Sample Input:

```
customer | contract_start | contract_end
CustA    | 2018-01-22     | 2019-01-22
CustA    | 2018-03-15     | 2019-03-15
CustA    | 2018-07-10     | 2019-07-10
CustA    | 2018-09-08     | 2018-12-10
CustB    | 2018-02-17     | 2018-11-17
CustB    | 2018-05-13     | 2019-05-13
CustB    | 2018-10-01     | 2019-10-01
CustB    | 2018-12-25     | 2019-12-25
```

Desired Output:

```
snapshot_day | customer | active_contracts
2018-01-31   | CustA    | 1
2018-02-28   | CustA    | 1
2018-03-31   | CustA    | 2
2018-04-30   | CustA    | 2
2018-05-31   | CustA    | 2
2018-06-30   | CustA    | 2
2018-07-31   | CustA    | 3
2018-08-31   | CustA    | 3
2018-09-30   | CustA    | 4
2018-10-31   | CustA    | 4
2018-11-30   | CustA    | 4
2018-12-31   | CustA    | 3
2018-01-31   | CustB    | 0
2018-02-28   | CustB    | 1
2018-03-31   | CustB    | 1
2018-04-30   | CustB    | 1
2018-05-31   | CustB    | 2
2018-06-30   | CustB    | 2
2018-07-31   | CustB    | 2
2018-08-31   | CustB    | 2
2018-09-30   | CustB    | 2
2018-10-31   | CustB    | 3
2018-11-30   | CustB    | 2
2018-12-31   | CustB    | 2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry thanks, I edited the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following. This isn't the most elegant solution, and it uses a utility table which isn't strictly necessary (and even less so if you're using MySQL 8 or later).

However, the use of subqueries should hopefully make the various steps towards the solution fairly easy to disentangle.

Also, my result differs from yours. This could be because I considered how many active contracts there were on the last day of the month, whereas you were actually after something slightly different. Equally, it might be because you simply made a mistake ;-)

Finally, if you want to make a calendar table for yourself, there are plenty of tutorials on that out there...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(customer VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,contract_start DATE NOT NULL
,contract_end DATE NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(customer,contract_start)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('CustA','2018-01-22','2019-01-22'),
('CustA','2018-03-15','2019-03-15'),
('CustA','2018-07-10','2019-07-10'),
('CustA','2018-09-08','2018-12-10'),
('CustB','2018-02-17','2018-11-17'),
('CustB','2018-05-13','2019-05-13'),
('CustB','2018-10-01','2019-10-01'),
('CustB','2018-12-25','2019-12-25');

SELECT a.snapshot
     , b.customer
     , COUNT(*) active_contracts
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT LAST_DAY(x.dt) snapshot
                  FROM calendar x
                  JOIN 
                     ( SELECT LAST_DAY(MIN(contract_start)) range_start
                            , LAST_DAY(MAX(contract_end)) range_end 
                         FROM my_table
                     ) y
                    ON x.dt BETWEEN range_start AND range_end
     ) a
  JOIN my_table b
    ON a.snapshot BETWEEN b.contract_start AND b.contract_end
 GROUP
    BY customer, snapshot     
 ORDER 
    BY customer, snapshot;

+------------+----------+------------------+
| snapshot   | customer | active_contracts |
+------------+----------+------------------+
| 2018-01-31 | CustA    |                1 |
| 2018-02-28 | CustA    |                1 |
| 2018-03-31 | CustA    |                2 |
| 2018-04-30 | CustA    |                2 |
| 2018-05-31 | CustA    |                2 |
| 2018-06-30 | CustA    |                2 |
| 2018-07-31 | CustA    |                3 |
| 2018-08-31 | CustA    |                3 |
| 2018-09-30 | CustA    |                4 |
| 2018-10-31 | CustA    |                4 |
| 2018-11-30 | CustA    |                4 |
| 2018-12-31 | CustA    |                3 |
| 2019-01-31 | CustA    |                2 |
| 2019-02-28 | CustA    |                2 |
| 2019-03-31 | CustA    |                1 |
| 2019-04-30 | CustA    |                1 |
| 2019-05-31 | CustA    |                1 |
| 2019-06-30 | CustA    |                1 |
| 2018-02-28 | CustB    |                1 |
| 2018-03-31 | CustB    |                1 |
| 2018-04-30 | CustB    |                1 |
| 2018-05-31 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2018-06-30 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2018-07-31 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2018-08-31 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2018-09-30 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2018-10-31 | CustB    |                3 |
| 2018-11-30 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2018-12-31 | CustB    |                3 |
| 2019-01-31 | CustB    |                3 |
| 2019-02-28 | CustB    |                3 |
| 2019-03-31 | CustB    |                3 |
| 2019-04-30 | CustB    |                3 |
| 2019-05-31 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2019-06-30 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2019-07-31 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2019-08-31 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2019-09-30 | CustB    |                2 |
| 2019-10-31 | CustB    |                1 |
| 2019-11-30 | CustB    |                1 |
+------------+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: that's it! very elegant solution, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try grouping by year and month as well:

```
SELECT 
    customer,
    COUNT(*) AS active_contracts,
    MONTH(contract_start) as month,
    YEAR(contract_start) as year
FROM
    my_table
GROUP BY customer, year, month
```